# String.Format() for floating point to display fixed number of places?

Tags: asp.net, number-formatting

If I want to display, say, 4 decimal points, what is the correct format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
String.Format("{0:0.0000}", floatNum);
```

That will always display four decimal places, regardless of what the value is. Other options can be found here: http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer this approach.

```
floatNum.ToString("N4")
```

Answer (score -1):

Notice that it rounds:

```
decimal d = 1.23456789M;
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("0.0000"));

// Output: 1.2345
```

As a format string, it would be:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.0000}", d);
```